# Decidability of completing Penrose tilings

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling, decidability, aperiodic-tiling

Is the following problem known to be un/decidable? Problem: Given a finite configuration of Penrose tiles in the plane, determine if there is an extension of the configuration tiling the whole plane.

Comment: Yes. Definition by local matching rules implies the set of extendable patterns is co-recursively enumerable, and minimality implies it is recursively enumerable.

Comment: By primitivity, for a patch of a particular radius, we know that we just need to look at the $n$th iterature of the substitution on a tile, where $n$ is a known function of $r$. If the patch is legal, it can be found in that supertile. If not, then it won't be found.

Comment: @DanRust: FWIW we said almost the same thing

Comment: @VilleSalo haha sorry, I was thinking more about the substitution definition, and I saw you'd mentioned matching rules so figured I would give a different approach.

Answer (score 10):

Apparently it is decidable, as proved in theorem 27 here: https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/ritter/masterclasses/ritter-lectures-on-penrose-tilings.pdf